# Confusion with simple Binomial Distribution example

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm following the paper available [here](http://sgpwe.izt.uam.mx/files/users/uami/lrm/Estadistica/A_Simple_Dataset_for_Demonstrating_Common_Distributions.docx). The Binomial distribution is used to calculate the probability of obtaining 26 babies of the same sex from a total of 44 births. If the probability of giving birth to a boy is equal to that of a girl then - according to the paper -

> The probability of observing at least 26 babies of the same sex in 44 births is **0.2912** under this assumption.

However if I calculate the probability of `x > 25` using the `pbinom()` function in R as

```
> pbinom(25, 44, 0.5, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.146
```

I realize that `0.146 + 0.146 = 0.291`, which could be taken to mean that the probability of getting 26 babies of the same sex = `P(x > 25) boys + P(x > 25) girls`. Is this reasoning correct? If yes, then when I change x to be `x = 21` then `P(x > 21) = 0.56`, in which case "probability of observing at least 22 children of the same sex would be `1.12` which seems wrong as the probabilities should be less than 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the second one, when number of boys is $22$, number of girls is also $22$. Both the number of boys and girls fall into the same event this time, unlike $26,18$ split. However, you count this probability twice when you multiply with $2$. Also, in either case, the probability $1$, because no matter how you split boys and girls, one of them will be larger than $21$.

Note: $P(X=22)\approx 0.12$, which is what you count twice.

Comment: This is a correct objection to the incorrect second method shown. (+1) The first method using R is OK if done correctly: `2*pbinom(25, 44, 0.5, lower.tail = FALSE)` returns 0.2912152.

Answer (score 1):

A table of possible outcomes in R; `event` is 'At least 26 of same sex'.
Outcomes that do not satisfy the event show `0`; not all of the 38 complementary possibilities are shown.

```
b = 0:44;  g = 44-b;  event = (g>=26 | b>=26)  # symbol '|' means OR
rbind(b, g, event)[ ,18:28]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
b       17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25    26    27
g       27   26   25   24   23   22   21   20   19    18    17
event    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     1
```

Probability: $P(\text{Event}) = 0.2912.$

```
sum(dbinom(b[event], 44, .5))
[1] 0.2912152
```

A good normal approximation (with continuity correction) is $P(\text{Event}) = 0.2913.$ [The normal approximation could also be done by standardizing and using normal tables, but with a little additional inaccuracy.]

```
1 - diff(pnorm(c(18.5, 25.5), 44/2, sqrt(44/4)))
[1] 0.2912928
```

In the figure below the exact binomial result is the sum of the heights of the
bars outside the vertical dotted lines. The thin black curve is the approximating normal PDF.

[image]